Improving a bound on the limit of the expected value of the longest increasing subsequence of length n.
Context:
I am following (self study) Dan Romik's The Surprising Mathematics of Longest Increasing Subsequences, August 2014 edition.
Denoting $L(\sigma_n)$ the longest increasing subsequence of a permutation $\sigma_n$ of length $n$, lemma 1.4 establishes the bound
$$
\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{E[L(\sigma_n)]}{\sqrt{n}} \leq e.
$$
A quick outline of the proof is as follows:
Denoting $X_{n,k}$ the number of increasing subsequences of $\sigma_n$ of length $k$ where $1 \leq k \leq n$, we have $E[X_{n,k}] = \frac{1}{k!} {n \choose k}$. Using this, we obtain
\begin{align}
P(L(\sigma_n) \geq k) &= P(X_{n,k} \geq 1) \leq E[X_{n,k}] = \frac{1}{k!} {n \choose k} \\
&= \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{(k!)^2} \leq \frac{n^k}{(k/e)^{2k}}.
\end{align}
Taking $k = \lceil (1+\delta)e \sqrt{n} \rceil$, for some fixed $\delta > 0$, we get
$$
P(L(\sigma_n) \geq k) \leq \left( \frac{1}{1+\delta}\right)^{2(1+\delta)e \sqrt{n}},
$$
which we can use to show that $E[L(\sigma_n)] \leq (1+\delta)e \sqrt{n} + O(e^{-c\sqrt{n}})$. Dividing by $\sqrt{n}$ and taking the limit, we get the above bound.

My question:
In exercise 1.1 (b), it is stated that we can use that if $L(\sigma_n) \geq t$ then $X_{n,k} \geq {t \choose k}$, taking $k \approx \alpha \sqrt{n}$, $t \approx \beta \sqrt{n}$ and optimizing over $\alpha < \beta$ to obtain
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{E[L(\sigma_n)]}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2.49,
$$
improving the bound established in lemma 1.4.
So far, I have tried the following:
Using $L(\sigma_n) \geq t \implies X_{n,k} \geq {t \choose k}$, we have
\begin{align}
P(L(\sigma_n) \geq t) \leq P\left(X_{n,k} \geq {t \choose k} \right) \leq \frac{n^k}{(k!)^2} \frac{1}{{t \choose k}} = \frac{n^k}{(k!)^2} \frac{k! (t-k)!}{t!}.
\end{align}
I then try to make the bound on the right-hand side as small as possible. To do this, we want to choose $k$ such that ${t \choose k}$ is as big as possible, so we take $k \approx t/2$. We then get
$$
\frac{n^k}{(k!)^2} \frac{k!(t-k)!}{t!} \approx \frac{n^k}{(k!)^2} \frac{k!(2k-k)!}{t!} = \frac{n^{\frac{1}{2} t}}{t!} \leq \frac{n^{\frac{1}{2} t}}{(t/e)^t}.
$$
But now it seems we are forced to take $t = (1+\delta)e\sqrt{n}$ which yields the same result as in lemma 1.4.
Any hints on how to proceed?

A seemingly not successful trail.
Following your idea, we have
\begin{equation}
\Pr[L(\sigma_n) \geq t] \leq \Pr[X_{n,k}\geq \binom{t}{k}] \leq \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k! \binom{t}{k}} = \frac{n! (t-k)!}{t!k!(n-k)!} \leq \frac{n^k}{k! (t - k)^k} \leq (\frac{ne}{k(t-k)})^k.
\end{equation}
If $k \approx \alpha \sqrt{n}$ and $t \approx \beta \sqrt{n}$, we have
\begin{equation}
(\frac{ne}{k(t-k)})^k \approx (\frac{e}{\alpha(\beta-\alpha)})^k \approx (\frac{e}{\alpha(\beta - \alpha)})^{\alpha \sqrt{n}}.
\end{equation}
This only allows us to find the bound $\beta \approx 2\sqrt{e} > e$..

Improved upon the failed trail
Following your idea, we have
\begin{equation} 
\Pr[L(\sigma_n) \geq t] \leq \Pr[X_{n,k}\geq \binom{t}{k}] \leq \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k! \binom{t}{k}} = \frac{n! (t-k)!}{t!k!(n-k)!} \leq \frac{n^k (t-k)!}{t!k!}.
\end{equation}
If $k \approx \alpha \sqrt{n}$ and $t \approx \beta \sqrt{n}$, by directly using Stirling's approximation, we have
\begin{equation} 
\frac{n^k (t-k)!}{t!k!} \approx \frac{n^k (\frac{t-k}{e})^{t-k}}{(\frac{k}{e})^{k} (\frac{t}{e})^{t}} = (\frac{\eta^\eta e^2}{(1+\eta)^{1 + \eta} \alpha^2})^k,
\end{equation}
where $\eta = \frac{t}{k} - 1 > 0$.
We aim to minimize $\beta = \alpha (1 + \eta)$, and we need at least $\frac{\eta^\eta e^2}{(1+\eta)^{1 + \eta} \alpha^2} \approx 1$, which gives
\begin{equation}
\beta \approx e \sqrt{\frac{\eta^\eta}{(\eta + 1)^{(\eta - 1)}}}.
\end{equation}
When $\eta \approx 0.255001$, $e \sqrt{\frac{\eta^\eta}{(\eta + 1)^{(\eta - 1)}}} \approx 2.48527$.


Very nice, thanks a lot!
